# Retrieving URL scheme variables from plain text

Tags: applescript

I need a way to retrieve URL scheme variables from a string of plain text. I'm starting from the following AppleScript:

```
set inputStr to "{query}"
set my text item delimiters to ": "
set taskName to first text item of inputStr
set listName to last text item of inputStr
set urlScheme to "app://url/add?color=" & color & "&height=" & height
tell application "System Events"
    open location urlScheme
end tell
```

There are about a dozen more possible variables (e.g, width, area, month, etc...) that I would like to add, but this solution of using "first text item" or "last text item" won't work practically because users won't be able to remember the proper order to enter the text string. Instead, what I would like is a way to parse the text identifying variables in whatever order they occur. For example, one user could input:

```
color: green height: 10 area: 14 month: July
```

And another:

```
height: 10 year: 2016 month: August
```

And the relevant portions of the URL scheme would be filled in with the remaining portions being left blank.

Answer (score 0):

Any program that expects the user to type a text string properly is asking for trouble, and needs to do massive amounts of error checking, but...
Give yourself a fighting chance and require the input to be in a more parseable format such as:

```
"color:green, height:10, area:14, month:July"
```

Then, set you AS delimiters to a comma, to get array entries in `"key:value"` format. In a loop, you can then process each array entry to append the key and value to the url as appropriate.

Do some additional sanity checking by stripping out leading and trailing spaces around keys and values, which the user may have added.